# why $|A_{E}(f) - \alpha| \le r $ give contradiction?

Tags: measure-theory

I have  some confusion in **RCA** book

My confusion given below  and marked in red box

[image]

My attempt  : Here  we  have already taken  $r >0 $ that is $r$ is positive

$|A_{E}(f) - \alpha|$is also $+ve$  since Mod  is always $+ve$

My doubt :  why $|A_{E}(f) - \alpha| \le r $ give  contradiction ?

Comment: $|A_E(f)-\alpha|\le r$ shows that $A_E(f)$ is inside the closed circular disc with radius $r$ centered at $\alpha$. But by assumption, this disc is in the complement of $S$, contradicting $A_E(f) \in S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $S$ is closed, we have that $S^\mathsf c$ is open. We want to prove $f(x)\in S$ a.e. by proving $\mu(f^{-1}(S^\mathsf c))=0$.

$S^\mathsf c$ is open (remember we're in the topology for the complex plane associated to the euclidean metric), and we have a countable base of closed discs centred at points of the form $p+qi$, such that $p,q\in\Bbb Q$, with radius $r\in\Bbb Q$. So if we prove that for any such closed disc $V$ in $S^\mathsf c$ we have $f^{-1}(V)$ has zero measure, then we'll have $\mu(f^{-1}(S^\mathsf c))=\mu(f^{-1}(\bigcup_i V_i))=\mu(\bigcup_i f^{-1}(V_i))\le \sum_i\mu(V_i)=0$.

In fact, it'll be proved the zero measure of any closed disc $V$ in $S^\mathsf c$ (let's say it's centred at $\alpha$ with radius $r$).  Denote $E=f^{-1}(V)$, which is measurable. Then $|f-\alpha|\le r$ on $E$, since $E$ is precisely the set of points whose images lie in the closed disc $V$. If we had $\mu(E)>0$, then by hypothesis

$\left|A_E(f)-\alpha\right|=\left|\frac{1}{\mu(E)}\int_E f\,\text{d}\mu-\alpha\frac{\mu(E)}{\mu(E}\right|=\frac{1}{\mu(E)}\left|\int_E f\,\text{d}\mu-\alpha\int_E 1\,\text{d}\mu\right|=\frac{1}{\mu(E)}\left|\int_E(f-\alpha)\,\text{d}\mu\right|\le$

$\le\frac{1}{\mu(E)}\int_E\left|f-\alpha\right|\text{d}\mu\le\frac{1}{\mu(E)}\int_E r\,\text{d}\mu=\frac{r}{\mu(E)}\int_E 1\,\text{d}\mu=r$, which means $A_E(f)$ is in the closed disc $V$, since the distance to its center $\alpha$ is less or equal to its radius $r$. But $V$ was a closed disc in $S^\mathsf c$, so we are saying that $A_E(f)\in V\subset S^\mathsf c$, which is impossible since we had $A_E(f)\in S$ for every measurable set $E$ with $\mu(E)>0$.

We conclude we actually had $\mu(f^{-1}(V))=\mu(E)=0$, which completes the proof.